# How to set timezone to EST in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS MySQL 5.7 instance which was set to time_zone as US/Eastern from the parameter group. Right now it was in EST (UTC−05:00) but I think it will change to EDT (UTC−04:00) on March 8 2020, but I don't want that to be happening. It would create a discrepancy in the data. It should always be in EST or UTC−05:00. I could not find an option to achieve this in rds parameter group. How to set the timezone to EST?

Note: I know that I should have created and set time zone to UTC initially to avoid all these griefs but its already done and a lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the set the time_zone parameter in the DB parameter group for the DB instance. A full guide is here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/

If you need to maintain the same -5 UTC, then I would find a time_zone that matches from here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00 and then match it to a time_zone setting from here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.LocalTimeZone

You may have to change it again, as different time zones have different daylight saving times, however once you know this for a whole year cycle, automating the changes when needed shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I figured out that America/Bogota (colombia standard time) in time_zone of RDS parameter group is always UTC-05:00 and dosen't have DST.

Comment: Yeah, that works for Jamaica as well